# Java: polymorphically call super implementation

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, super

Suppose I have this:

```java
public class A { 
  public String foo() { return "A"; } 
}

public class B extends A { 
  public String foo() { return "B"; } 
  public String superFoo() { return super.foo(); }
}

public class C extends B { 
  public String foo() { return "C"; } 
}
```

Here, `new C().superFoo()` returns `"A"`.
Is there a way I can polymorphically make `new C().superFoo()` invoke `B.foo()` (and hence return `"B"`) without the need to override `superFoo()` in `C`?
I tried with reflection (redefining `B.superFoo()` like this: `return getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("foo").invoke(this)`), hoping that with `getDeclaredMethod` I could reference the exact method implementation in superclass, but I get `"C"` in that case (hence, polymorphism is applied).

I was searching for a solution that doesn't require me to redeclare `superFoo()` whenever I add a new subclass to the hierarchy.

Comment: why do you need to even define superFoo() ? if its just super.foo()    can you not just call super.foo() ?    else show an example of how you will use superFoo()

Comment: This is just a proof-of-concept. First, `new C().super.foo()` is not valid code. Second, in my real-world case, the call to super.foo() is within a method implementation that would need to access the super implementation polymorphically, so extracting the call to `super.foo()` into a `superFoo()` method is just a convenience and a way to easily (if at all possible) implement this concept of "polymorphic super call".

Comment: Please put your proof of concept on a firm foundation of a [mre] which actually demonstrates your context. Otherwise you will be theorising and ending up with no answers or answers which later turn out not to help with what you are actually trying to do. Or to put it differently: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not searching for an alternate solution to my actual business case (which is fairly complex) or whether my approach is the best one to solve it. This question is really specific and already contains a runnable test case that clearly explains the actual result vs the desired result. So, if the answer is just that it's not possible, or that it's not reasonably possible, that should be the right answer.

Comment: just a bit odd - that you need super.foo() independently of foo() implies there is some out of context mutation/processing. can you move that logic out as visitor or something else?

Comment: While I agree it's an ugly requirement, the world is an ugly place and the theoretical question here is quite clear. Can we write a method that generically calls <super of instance>.method().

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Going through the question and comments, it seems like the ask here is to incrementally build up on a behavior. Taking a different perspective, I would prefer **Composition over Inheritance** in this scenario.

You can use Decorator pattern and compose the instances together; which in turn gives you a reference to the parent's `foo()` implementation. One of the other benefits is that you can extend/change the behavior at runtime, which is not possible with a static inheritance design.

---

**About Decorator Pattern**

Decorator pattern can be used to attach additional responsibilities to an object either statically or dynamically.

- `Component` - Interface for objects that can have responsibilities added to them dynamically.
- `ConcreteComponent` - Defines an object to which additional responsibilities can be added.
- `Decorator` - Maintains a reference to a Component object and defines an interface that conforms to Component's interface.
- `Concrete Decorators` - Concrete Decorators extend the functionality of the component by adding state or adding behavior.

[image]

**Sample Code**

Let's take a Pizza baking process as an example.

`Component` interface - Defines the contract that a Pizza must be baked.

```
public interface Pizza {
    void bake();
}
```

`ConcreteComponent` class - This is your implementation of the interface which can stand alone by itself. It should not extend the `Decorator` and it appears at the innermost position when the objects are composed together (see client code at the end)

```
public class VeggiePizza implements Pizza {
    @Override
    public void bake() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Veggie Pizza in the making :)");
    }
}
```

`Decorator` - Specifies a contract for extending the functionality of the `ConcreteComponent`.

```
public abstract class Topping implements Pizza {

    private Pizza pizza;

    public Topping(Pizza pizza) {
        this.pizza = pizza;
    }

    @Override
    public void bake() {
        pizza.bake();
    }
}
```

`Concrete Decorator` - These implementations add to the functionality of the `ConcreteComponent` by nesting their constructors together (one of the ways to compose!). The concrete decorator can appear anywhere while composing, except for the innermost position (see client code below).

Here we are defining two toppings - Mushroom and Jalapeno.

```
public class Mushroom extends Topping {

     public Mushroom(Pizza pizza) {
         super(pizza);
     }

    @Override
    public void bake() {
         addMushroom();
         super.bake();
    }

    private void addMushroom() {
         System.out.println("Adding mushrooms...");
    }
}

public class Jalapeno extends Topping {

    public Jalapeno(Pizza pizza) {
        super(pizza);
    }

    @Override
    public void bake() {
        addJalapenos();
        super.bake();
    }

    private void addJalapenos() {
        System.out.println("Adding jalapenos...");
    }

}
```

**Client code** - How do you compose the `ConcreteDecorator` and `ConcreteComponent`together?

```
public void bakePizza() {
    Pizza pizza = new Mushroom(new Jalapeno(new VeggiePizza()));
    pizza.bake();
}
```

Notice that we build upon the `VeggiePizza` by wrapping the objects around with additional behavior from `Mushroom` and `Jalapeno`. Here, the `ConcreteComponent` is the innermost `VeggiePizza`, while our `ConcreteDecorator`s are `Jalapeno` and `Mushroom`.

**Note:** Constructor composition is only one of the ways to compose. You can compose object together via setters or use a Dependency Injection framework.

**Output**

```
Adding mushrooms...
Adding jalapenos...
I'm a Veggie Pizza in the making :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will return `B` though I've omitted various safety features for the sake of brevity and used `commons-lang` because you don't want to have to do this stuff yourself! At a minimum, this code assumes every class defines `foo()` and the you never directly call `a.superFoo()!` :)

```java
    public String superFoo() {
      return superXXX("foo");
    }

    private <T> T superXXX(String name, Object... args) {
      Method overriddenMethod = MethodUtils.getAccessibleMethod(getClass(), name);
      Iterator<Method> methods = MethodUtils.getOverrideHierarchy(overriddenMethod, EXCLUDE).iterator();
      methods.next(); // this is C
      Method parentMethod = methods.next(); // This is B;

      try {
        return (T)parentMethod.invoke(this, args);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
```

FYI. There may well be an AspectJ/Javassist/Bytebuddy style solution possible as well whereby you can reimplement the `superFoo` method on all children of `A` to be `super.foo()`