# How to override a method with supertype-argument

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, overriding

I have a `Fruit` class like this.

```
open class Fruit(var taste: String) {

    open fun consume(from: Fruit) {
        taste = from.taste
    }
}
```

I have an `Apple` class that extends `Fruit` class like this.

```
class Apple(
    var color: String,
    taste: String
): Fruit(taste) {

    // caution: method overrides nothing
    override fun consume(from: Apple) {
        super.consume(from)
        color = from.color
    }
}
```

This is my usage code:

```
val fruit: Fruit = Apple(color = "green", taste = "sweet")
val badFruit = Apple(
    color = anyOf("red", "blue", "golden"),
    taste = anyOf("sour+", "sweet+", "chilli+")
)

fruit.consume(from = badFruit)

println("BadFruit: $badFruit")
println("InfectedFruit: $fruit")
```

#### Problem:

I can't override following method in `Apple` class:

```
override fun consume(from: Apple) {
    super.consume(from)
    color = from.color
}
```

To correctly override this method, I need to pass in an instance of Fruit class(as in super method). If I do this, I will always have to check if `Fruit` instance is actually `Apple` instance. But, shouldn't it just work with former because `Apple` extends `Fruit`?

How can I achieve such functionality that when I call `consume()` on `fruit: Fruit = Apple(...)`, it actually calls `Apple#consume()` method?

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be a case of XY problem and composition can be helpful here instead of 'static inhertiance'. You might want to check out my answer on a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188318/java-polymorphically-call-super-implementation/63191535#63191535 . Also, please do provide some more information about the actual problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you want the Apple class to only consume Apples then just make the Fruit class generic contravariant parameter. Or if wanted to accept both, then just accept Fruit and do an if check if the instance is of Apple and if yes change the color property.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I wanted to avoid using generics. But, seems fair, this will require "Producer In, Consumer out" kind of implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While technical alternatives have been suggested in comments, I'd like to add another perspective. What we're seeing here is a class design problem which comes up when attempting to use inheritance for anything other than a true generalization/specialization relationship.

The example declares:

1. Each `Fruit` must be able to `consume` another `Fruit`.
2. An `Apple` is a kind of `Fruit`.

Then the idea is:

- An `Apple` must not `consume` any kind of `Fruit`, but an `Apple` only.

If an `Apple` were really a `Fruit`, it would fully adhere to the `Fruit`'s declaration and be able to `consume` another `Fruit` of any kind. As the intended apple `Apple` violates rule 1, is not really a `Fruit` and the language prevents you from declaring it as such.

Trying to work around this (e.g. via runtime checks in overridden methods) masquerades the underlying problem and introduces surprises to those using such classes.

Solution:

- Use inheritance for true generalization/specialization relationships only. If it is 100% certain, no strings attached, that *an apple **is a** fruit*, inheritance is a perfect fit. Otherwise it is not.
- In this case: Rethink the intended semantics:

  - What's the real meaning of `consume`?
  - Is there a notion of a fruit consuming an arbitrary (potentially incompatible specialization of another) fruit?
  - Or is it rather individual specializations of fruit which each have their own independent notion of consuming? Then there would be no common `consume` method at the `Fruit` level.

#### Copying Derived Classes via References To A Base Class

Answering the additional question in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634070/how-to-override-a-method-with-supertype-argument/63637199#comment112579421_63637199):

> how can I make sure this will copy properties of both SourFruit and CoreFruit?

I'd rather not express `SweetFruit` and `SourFruit` as specializations of a `CoreFruit`. Flavors such as sweet and sour are traits of a fruit and better expressed as properties.

But I could extend your example a bit and then suggest a class design which includes a `clone()` function providing a deep copy functionality on a base class `Flavor`. Note that the output shows different hash codes for cloned objects:

```kotlin
data class Fruit(var weight: Double, var flavors: MutableList<Flavor>) {
    fun clone(): Fruit {
        return Fruit(weight, flavors.map { it.clone() }.toMutableList())
    }
}

abstract class Flavor {
    abstract fun clone(): Flavor
}

class SweetFlavor(var intensity: Int, var isHealthy: Boolean) : Flavor() {
    override fun clone(): Flavor {
        return SweetFlavor(intensity, isHealthy)
    }
}

class SourFlavor(var intensity: Int) : Flavor() {
    override fun clone(): Flavor {
        return SourFlavor(intensity)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val apple = Fruit(0.2, mutableListOf(SweetFlavor(4, true), SourFlavor(2)))
    val lemon = Fruit(0.35, mutableListOf(SourFlavor(9)))
    val appleClone = apple.clone()

    println("apple: $apple")
    println("lemon: $lemon")
    println("appleClone: $appleClone")

    appleClone.weight += 0.5
    appleClone.flavors[0] = SweetFlavor(6, false)

    println("apple: $apple")
    println("appleClone: $appleClone")
}
```

Comment: I agree with you on inheritance advice. As an example, suppose I have is a CoreFruit. It contains basic properties like size and weight. I create two subclasses of CoreFruit; called SourFruit and SweetFruit. Now, if SourFruit is in a `List` of type CoreFruit, and I intend to create a copy of underlying SourFruit manually, like `sourFruitButTypedAsFruit.copy()`; how can I make sure this will copy properties of both SourFruit and CoreFruit? `consume()` is similar but it writes a Fruit onto another. Can you show example?

Comment: See the added section _Copying Derived Classes via References To A Base Class_ in the above answer.